# regex for allowing SINGLE white space in between words

Tags: regex

I m using the following regex for the same:
^\S.*\S$

but this regex is not working in case of multiple spaces in between words.
and one more thing, it doesnt allow you to enter a single character

I want to validate no leading and trailing space and single white space in between words, words can include anything alphanumeric as well as special character.

if i m trying to enter 'a' in the text box, its not accepting

Comment: "Working" and "not working" suggest you know what you want, but I can't tell from reading this what that is.  Provide some examples of input and desired output and you'll get better answers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Post some examples for valid and invalid matches.

Comment: this regex should give true for following: shashank shekhar

Comment: but wrong for Shashank   Shekhar, it should not allow multiple spaces in between both the words

Comment: It will be better if your provide examples here. For input A expected output will be B.

Comment: @ShashankShekhar post it in your question.

Comment: Sorry, i m new to this blog..
in comments, its not taking multiple spaces in between two words

Comment: Add example in your question, not in comments,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^\S+(?: \S+)*$
```

`\S` matches any non-space character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cC3hY7/3)

Answer (score 5):

In case only charactors are needed, use this:

```
^[a-z|A-Z]+(?: [a-z|A-Z]+)*$
```

Comment: How do I accept unicode latin characters as well?

Answer (score 1):

Below one allows one space between words with some special chars. It also prevent space at starting and end of string.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9@.,]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9@.,]+$
```

Comment: How do I accept unicode latin characters as well?

Answer (score 0):

[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)? you can use this to put single space between words

Comment: i need to use alphanumeric as well as special characters and its not working if i want to enter a single character

Comment: @ShashankShekhar why you failed to add explanation in your question?

Comment: How do I accept unicode latin characters as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just assert that two spaces don't appear;

```
^(?!.*\s\s)\S(.*\S)?$
```